# Converting 8 byte char array into long

Tags: c, arrays, types, shift

How do we convert 8 byte char array into long since `<<` does not work for type long?

```
#define word_size 8

long num = 0;
char a[word_size] = "\x88\x99\xaa\x0bb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff";

for (i=0; i < word_size;i++) {
   a[(word_size-1) - i] |= (num << (8*(word_size - i - 1))) & 0xFF;
}

printf("%lx\n", num);
```

Comment: `<<` works fine with `long`. In this case, `num` is always 0, and so you're clearing `a` to all 0s.

Comment: `long` is not necessarily 64 bits. If you want to make sure, use `int64_t` from `stdint.h`. That is the proposed way. Also, make sure the array has the proper byte-order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code is more efficient:

```
unsigned char[word_size] = ...;
int64_t num = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(a) ; i++ )
    num = (num << 8) | a[i];
```

This assumes big endian (highest order byte first) ordering of the bytes in the array. For little endian (as you appear to use) just process it top-down:

```
for ( int i = sizeof(a) ; --i >= 0 ; )
```

Note: whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-dependent, so nail it down to be unsigned, otherwise the logical-or will not work. Better use `uint8_t`; that is defined to be 8 bits, while `char` is *not*.

Note: You should use all-uppercase for constants: `WORD_SIZE` instead of `word_size`. That is a commonly accepted standard (quite the only about case for identifiers in C).

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to convert an 8-byte char array into a long long and this was the only way to make it happen that I could find.

Comment: @DaveCole: I'm happy it helped. Just remember to be careful when shifting signed values. I generally strongly recommend to use `unsigned` types only for shifting. Also note that `long long` is not required to have 64 bits and a byte/`char` (see text) does not need to have 8 bits either. Using the correct types makes your code more self-documenting. Even if that is no production code, you might value that in some years.