# How to get IP Options from sk_buff?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, ip, packet

I'm trying to retrieve IP Options' data from IP packet in Linux with c++. This code finds out a packet has IP option but the problem is I cant get IP Options value. Is there a way to get IP Options' data?

```
#include <linux/ip.h>

if(key->eth.type == htons(ETH_P_IP) && key->ip.tos != 0)
{
    struct iphdr *nh = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

    if(nh != NULL && nh->ihl * 4 > sizeof(struct iphdr))
    {
         // get IP options
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably state which options you want to retrieve.

Comment: I want to retrieve timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to access each byte of network header. So after typical header there are IP options bytes. In case of timestamp IP options' first byte is `type`, second is `length` and third is `overflow` and `flags`. Thus fourth byte is start of actual IP options data. In my solution I try to convert data to `unsigned long int`.

```
struct iphdr *nh = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb); // skb is socket buffer

unsigned int iphdr_size = sizeof(struct iphdr);

if(nh != NULL && nh->ihl * 4 > iphdr_size)
{
    u8 *opt;
    opt = (u_int8_t *)nh;

    unsigned long int optdata = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    for(i = iphdr_size + 4; i < nh->ihl * 4; i++)
    {
        optdata = (optdata << 8) | opt[i];
    }
    // Now we have data in optdata, do what you want to do
}
```

There were some useful links such as:
[IP & TCP Option Functions](https://forum.kernelnewbies.org/read.php?15,1011)
[Converting 8 byte char array into long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720546/converting-8-byte-char-array-into-long)